# What is MBE Style illustrations?

Tags: style-identification

I was looking to find certain type of icon styles and after a long search, i have got its name as "MBE Style" in dribbble. It is in such a huge trend. I am trying to learn its history. So can anyone help me answer these questions?

1. Why is it called MBE style?
2. Is there a particular standard to work on these icons?
3. Who found this trend?

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74294/are-there-any-tutorials-on-how-to-emulate-mbes-style)

I am trying to understand its basics. Your answers are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried asking that MBE user on dribble? I'd start from there.

Comment: Well, i never knew that this style comes from a user's name in dribbble.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a user on dribbble who's username is `MBE`.
I get the sense this is named as a reference to his own style of illustration.

In which case there is likely not a formal standard for it.

[MBE on dribbble](https://dribbble.com/Madebyelvis)
[image: MBE on dribbble]